# Directory structure based auto-updating video library application

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a collection of movies/full tv series stored on an external hard drive. As of now all the files are sorted in a directory hierarchy at the top of which there are just two folders, "`Movies`" and "`TV series`". The "`Movies`" folder is further sorted in a 1-level-deep directory hierarchy containing a folder for each different genre. This structure it's prone to be changed/slightly modified often.

I process any new file to be addedd to this library by running a script which edits its tags and renames it based on some criteria before adding it to the right folder.

I'd like to browse the whole collection from a video library application which can show me the files' tags, thumbnails and which can allow me to search the whole collection, but **mostly it should be able to update its content based on the current collection's directory structure**.

Is there a video library application which can do such things (perhaps displaying the whole directory hierarchy as multiple "recursively nested" playlists)?

Comment: I guess you are referring to a GUI application, not CLI?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, meaning that I'd like to browse the collection from a GUI, but I wouldn't mind if the "mostly it should be able to update its content based on the current collection's directory structure" part would require a script to be run before the launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XBMC Media Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xbmc) [image: Install XBMC Media Center]

To install it via command-line:

1. Update the `apt` cache: `sudo apt-get update`
2. Install XMBC Media Center: `sudo apt-get install xbmc`

To run it via command-line:

1. Run `xbmc`: `xbmc`

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]
[image: Screenshot 4]